# Dynamic column rename based on a separate data frame in R

Tags: r, indexing

Generate `df1` and `df2` like this

```
pro <- c("Hide-Away", "Hide-Away")
sourceName <- c("New Rate2", "FST")
standardName <- c("New Rate", "SFT") 
df1 <- data.frame(pro, sourceName, standardName, stringsAsFactors = F)
A <- 1; B <- 2; C <-3; D <- 4; G <- 5; H <- 6; E <-7; FST <-8; Z <-8
df2<- data.frame(A,B,C,D,G,H,E,FST)
colnames(df2)[1]<- "New Rate2"
```

Then run this code.

```
df1 <- df1[,c(2,3)]
index<-which(colnames(df2) %in% df1[,1])
index2<-which(df1[,1] %in% colnames(df2) )
colnames(df2)[index] <- df1[index2,2]
```

The input of `DF2` will be like

```
  New Rate2 B C D G H E FST
          1 2 3 4 5 6 7   8
```

The output of `DF2` will be like

```
  New Rate B C D G H E SFT
         1 2 3 4 5 6 7   8
```

So clearly the code worked and swapped the names correctly. But now create `df2` with the below code instead. And make sure to regenrate `df1` to what it was before.

```
df2<- data.frame(FST,B,C,D,G,H,E,Z)
colnames(df2)[8]<- "New Rate2"
```

and then run

```
df1 <- df1[,c(2,3)]
index<-which(colnames(df2) %in% df1[,1])
index2<-which(df1[,1] %in% colnames(df2) )
colnames(df2)[index] <- df1[index2,2]
```

The input of `df2` will be

```
 FST B C D G H E New Rate2
   8 2 3 4 5 6 7         8
```

The output of `df2` will be

```
New Rate B C D G H E SFT
       8 2 3 4 5 6 7   8
```

So the order of the columns has not been preserved. I know this is because of the `%in` code but I am not sure of an easy fix to make the column swapping more dynamic.

Comment: Is it possible to ask your question at the top before explaining what you have done? It might help clarify the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not totally sure about the question, as it seems a little vague. I'll try my best though--the best way I know to dynamically set column names is `setnames` from the `data.table` package. So let's say that I have a set of source names and a set of standard names, and I want to swap the source for the standard (which I take to be the question).

Given the data above, I have a data.frame structured like so:

```
> df2
  A B C D G H E FST
1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7   8
```

as well as two vectors, sourceName and standardName.

```
sourceName <- c("A", "FST")
standardName <- c("New A", "FST 2: Electric Boogaloo")
```

I want to dynamically swap sourceName for standardName, and I can do this with `setnames` like so:

```
df3 <- as.data.table(df2)
setnames(df3, sourceName, standardName)

> df3
   New A B C D G H E FST 2: Electric Boogaloo
1:     1 2 3 4 5 6 7                        8
```

Comment: nice sunny reference

Answer (score 0):

Trying to follow your example, in your second pass I get an index value of 0,

```
> df2
  New Rate B C D G H E SFT
1        8 2 3 4 5 6 7   8
> df1
  sourceName standardName
1  New Rate2     New Rate
2        FST          SFT
> index<-which(colnames(df2) %in% df1[,1])
> index
integer(0)
```

which would account for your expected ordering on assignment to column names.